# Разный header с react routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Вообщем я практикуюсь в создании сайта на React js. Я подключил react-router-dom и сделал чтобы можно было переходить по страницам. Но мне нужно чтобы при переходе на определенную страницу header изменялся на другой(у меня есть 2 компонента, первый для всех страниц кроме регистрации, второй для регистрации). Не могу понять как реализовать смену header при переходе на определенную страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда Вы переходите на страницу `react-router` передает в `props` переменную `match`, в которой записан текущий URL и прочая информация о странице. Но для этого в роуте надо передать `exact` свойство:

```
<Route path={`/`} component={HomePage} exact></Route>
```

Далее необходимо передавать в header данную информацию. Если хедер не является дочерним компонентом (что логично если правильно организовали структуру), а глобальный, то можете воспользоваться `redux` к примеру для синхронизации состояний компонентов не являющиеся между собой дочерними-родительскими.

Алгоритм такой:

При переходе на страницу в конструкторе записываете данную инфу в стейт глобальный через redux
Далее считываете её хедером,
и вызываете метод сравнения из области: `if (path == '/registration') ...` меняете стили хедера на такой и т.д. или флаг на тот или иной компонент, всё уже от реализации зависит

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.